# Extracting weights from a classifier's posterior distribution

Tags: probability, classification, multi-class, reinforcement-learning, weights

Given a classifier $C$ that gets text as an input and outputs a posterior distribution $p_1\dots p_n$ on $n$ possible topics.

In other words, for each user post, I have a list of probabilities $\{p_i\}$ that represent the chance that the user was writing about topic $i$.

I would like to calculate weights $w_i=f(p_i)$ such that the weight would be negative if the user is very not likely to write about a topic, and positive if the user is very likely to write about a topic.

What would be the standard way to do this transformation ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Logit](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Logit) function as a start, i.e

$$ w_i = \log \left( \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right)$$

The weights will have a range of about $[-8, 8]$

Comment: I was thinking about using the `logit` but I quite alot of time $p_i$ is very close to zero, which causes the weights to explode to negative infinity